# phpstorm SSH won't bring me the next button

Tags: authentication, ssh, phpstorm

How can I use a SSH / SFTP connection to my server using phpstorm?

If I add a remote Server, I can choose the private Key file (putty) but he won't activate the "Next" button :( If I say "Login as anonymous" it will highlight the Next-button but thats not what I want :):)

I've searched the Docs but dind't find an helpful answer. Maybe you got the same problem in past?

EDIT:
As answered, I set up the server informations. Now, it returns me an error:

```
Server 'Check' is not valid: <html>Keypair 'C:\Program Files\putty\riegelp.ppk' is corrupt or 
has unknown format.<br> Only SSH2 keys in OpenSSH format or PuTTY Private Key *.ppk keys are 
supported.<br> Error message: The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.
</html>.
```

Answer (score 69):

This is caused by Java not coming with the necessary encryption packages in its default install. PHPStorm is bundled with its own copy of Java so this needs to have the extended encryption added.

First work out which version of Java has come with your PHPStorm install, this can be done by finding the PHPStorm java.exe location and running it from the cmd with -version e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8.0.1\jre\jre\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
```

Next download the correct "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files"

- Java 6 :
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html
- Java 7 :
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html
- Java 8 :
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Follow the install docs, you replace the following files in the security dir with the new ones from the download

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8.0.1\jre\jre\lib\security
local_policy.jar
US_export_policy.jar
```

Open up PHPStorm and SFTP with aes encrypted keys should be working

Comment: A quick note for those who might have a separate version of java installed and a similar setup to mine:  the path above existed, but updating the archive files there didn't work for me -- updating those in this directory did: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\jre\lib\security .  Many thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 25):

source: http://baligena.com/ssh-private-key-conversion/

In attempt to login into a ssh server using a private key in phpstorm I ran 
accross this error.

Keypair 'private_key.ppk' is corrupt or has unknown format. Only SSH2 keys in OpenSSH format or PuTTY Private Key *.ppk are supported.  Error message:  The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.

This error will not allow the "next" and "test connection" button to appear

The issue here is that the private key format is incorrect. You'll will need to convert the private key to open ssh format.  And the way to do that is

Open your private key in PuTTYGen

Top menu “Conversions”->”Export OpenSSH key”.

Save the new OpenSSH key when prompted.

Comment: Worked like a champ for me.  The default key generated by PuTTYGen is not OpenSSH compliant, so this fixed it up.

Comment: This solution is much better because replacing the jre break updates from jetbrains. Exporting as openssh won't mess with updates to the program.

Comment: It Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Edit Jan 2018**: It seems that since some time in 2017 JetBrains packs their IDEs with 64-bit Java by default and they supply the needed policy jars within **jre64\lib\security\policy** folder. That makes things much simpler, as there is no need to install a copy of 64-bit JDK manually in one of those folders listed below and to copy security files there.

To fix the issue now, navigate to **%IDE_ROOT%\jre64\lib\security** directory and copy files over from an underlying **policy\unlimited** folder.

**Original:**

While [the answer chris has given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136976/phpstorm-ssh-wont-bring-me-the-next-button/26682459#26682459) is the correct one, one more clarification is in order. If you are using any JetBrains' product **in 64-bit mode**, then be aware, that 64-bit Java is not packed with it. You must download and install 64-bit Java DK (not JRE) yourself.

That can be the reason behind rawb's comment to chris' answer — the IDE is falling back to system-level Java. I would not recommend to follow through with rawb's advice and replace security files in your system Java. Instead, it is better to configure your IDE to run under a different copy of Java.

[This article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) at JetBrains' support pages on selecting the version of Java the IDE will run under gives an insight in the order JDK version is looked up in. It's a little outdated as far as I can tell. If what is written there does not work for you, here's the order I figured to be working:

1. **%YOURIDE%_JDK_64** environment variable; in case of PHPStorm it is **PHPSTORM_JDK_64**, for WebStorm it is **WEBIDE_JDK_64**, etc.
2. **%IDE_ROOT%\jre64** directory
3. System **Registry**
4. **JDK_HOME** environment variable
5. **JAVA_HOME** environment variable

Now, install (or copy system-level) JDK under one of those paths and replace files as suggested.

You will have to tend to this copy of Java yourself, but, in my opinion, it will be more secure than to change system-wide JDK properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but a work around I found while running into the same problem.  I was trying to open a project from existing code on a remote bitnami server.  WebStorm was not accepting my .ppk file but putty was just fine, I finally just downloaded a .pem file from bitnami and WebStorm was able to use that.  So if you can get your hands on a .pem keypair, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jce_policy jars according to your jdk version and replace the jars in this location "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security" and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem persists, create a key using command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`. With the release of the latest version openssh 7.9, nothing helped solve the problem until I entered this command.