# SFTP connection returns "Auth cancel"

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2016.2.1, Windows 10. I'm trying to connect to remote host via SFTP. Credentials are correct. When I'm testing the connection, I have this error:

```
Connection to 'foobar.com' failed.
Auth cancel
```

I can connect using FileZilla. I've cleared PhpStorm known_hosts. On different machines (PC, Mac) connection works perfect. Tried key pair auth, disable antivirus/firewall - same error. Traditional FTP connection on port 21 works perfect.

I have no idea what is wrong. Any ideas?

// update: 2017.1: same issue

Answer (score 4):

"Auth cancel" is a SSH error (and SFTP works over SSH), and it means that an authenticator failed critically (or all of them failed).

If at all possible, set debug to max (-vvv) on the server's SSHd and see what error it reports exactly. This way you'll be sure of what's really happenig.

Failing that, these are some random attempts:

Usually this is caused by a key mismatch, or by an authenticator that is not implemented correctly by the client. For example if PHPStorm's SSH auth using public-key or keyboard-interactive malfunctioned, and the server allowed it, and no other authenticators were available before that, you would get "Auth cancel", and to solve it you would need to:

- either disable the failing auth module on the server (unless it is the last, in which case it would change nothing)
- or change the order of authenticators in the client and/or server to ensure a working authenticator gets a chance to play first

One possibility is to try all authenticators one at a time, both on server and client, until you find one that works. Then put it first in the authenticator list on the server.

## Update

I'm trying to set up a SFTP connection to a server in PHPStorm 2017.1:

```
Settings > Building, Execution, Deployment > Deployment > Options
```

I create a new server ("Remote Server")

```
Connection tab:

Type: [ SFTP      ]

SFTP host: [ my host    ]
Port     : [ 22 ]
Root path: [ /var/www/default/htdocs ]
User name: [ lserni ]
Auth type: [ Password ]
Password : [ *********** ] [x] Save password
```

and it worked (I needed to supply a password). You can set `Auth type` to "Key pair" and in that case PHPStorm asks for the private key (either in PuTTY or OpenSSH format - that's nice, as I use PuTTY on Windows; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use) you'll find how to generate both and convert between them. OpenSSH public keys are stored in `/home/your-remote-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the server) with its passphrase.

## Possible causes of failure

**Identity mismatch between local `known_hosts` (in Windows 7, it is C:\Users\YourName.ssh\known_hosts) and server identification**. Solution: remove the `known_hosts` file on Windows. It will be correctly re-created at the next connection. I successfully recreated this by simply regenerating the server key.

**Cipher mismatch between local PHPStorm and remote OpenSSH server**. I had to pretty wreck the OpenSSH server to do this, but it can be done. Check out on the SSH server the line specifying ciphers (if there is none, then it is the default). *Apparently* my own PHPStorm uses AES-CBC-256, but it actually depends on the Java version that PHPStorm uses. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136976/phpstorm-ssh-wont-bring-me-the-next-button) for more info. Again, adding [logging to the server SSHd](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting) should tell something useful:

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
Subsystem internal-sftp -l DEBUG3
```

(comment them with # after you're done - syslog debug file is going to be appreciably massive).

If this is the problem you will get

```
no matching cipher found: client aes256-cbc server [everything but].
```

Solution: set a shared Ciphers that work in sshd_config. In the case above, "aes256-cbc" must appear in the ciphers. Unfortunately what the ciphers *are* depends on client Java package, which may vary. I believe I have a vanilla install and it uses AES-256-CBC, so removing aes256-cbc made it fail, and putting it back made it work again. Some servers might prefer CTR by default, and not have CBC at all, and this *might* explain the failure. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18538/aes256-cbc-vs-aes256-ctr-in-ssh) for more.

Comment: Thank you! So I enabled debug and the result is: `2017-04-04 22:16:28,619 [1031282]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password 
2017-04-04 22:16:28,619 [1031282]  DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive 
2017-04-04 22:16:28,697 [1031360]   WARN - Deployment.config.SftpUserInfo - Unsupported keyboard interactive request: destination="xxx@example.com:222", name="", instruction="", prompt=["Hasło: "]`
I have no idea how to force "password" authenticator in PhpStorm :/

Comment: But you ought to also have key authentication in the server. Either PHPStorm is not advertising it, or the server is not supporting it. Can you check the server's options?

Comment: Server info: `preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password`. I set `Auth type` to "Key pair" (private key with passphrase), still "Auth cancel" :( Ofc public key is uploaded.

Comment: OK, later I will set up mine with a public key pair. Something is failing there. Public key not known to the server?

Comment: I've found out two possible causes of SFTP SSH public-key auth failure; see if they are of any help.

Comment: Thank you for your support and time, really! I'm gonna do some tests later, will be back.